# How to resize IE Developer tools when they are too big for the window

Tags: internet-explorer, ie11-developer-tools

I've been assigned to look at an IE only JavaScript issue. As such I wanted to use the IE Developer tools. I last used these when I was in the office with the computer plugged into a large monitor. Now I'm at home and have a smaller screen.

When I open the developer tools I'm finding that they are sized too large to fit into a maximized window. As such I have no access to the tabs to switch page etc. Any idea how to resize the developer tools to get out of this?

[image]

Comment: There's a button on the right hand corner where you can pin the dev tools to the same window you're using to browser instead or ctrl+p

Answer (score 21):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> worked best for me.

When the debugger is in the foreground, Ctrl+P unpins the debugger (rather than executing a "Print" command).

Comment: Wrong answer, Because Ctrol+P opens Print dialog.

Comment: @Ziaullah when in the IE11 debugger, Ctrl + P does make the debugger pop out, at least in version 11.0.9600.19659.

Answer (score 4):

There may be other ways to solve this but here is what I actually did:

1. Un-maximize the browser window
2. Make the window as big as possible without maximizing it
3. Use the title bar to drag the window as far down as possible so that the window is hanging off the bottom of the screen
4. Use the mouse to resize the window by dragging the top edge of the window up
5. The tabs were then displayed.

Comment: Surprisingly, IE didn't let me vertically resize the window larger than screen itself. This may have been because I was in a VM. However, I was able to reload the VM on a monitor with higher resolution where I was able to drag the debugger down.

Answer (score 2):

Press F11 to make it full screen and it will display the tabs.  Hover over the top of the developer tools right above the tabs and drag down.  Press F11 again to exit full screen and the developer tools should remain the same size at the bottom of the browser screen.